# Performing a post request using Rest Assured DSL

Tags: rest-assured

this is the body of my post request

```
{
    "Type": "Something",
    "Authentication": [
        {
            "Key": "key1",
            "Value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "key2",
            "Value": "value2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "key3",
            "Value": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not quite sure how to simulate sending the parameters for my post request for the post payload above.

I assumed sending everything as a key value pair but have not accounted for the nesting in the Authentication which is an array. As excepted I get a 400 Bad Request.

I would appreciate understanding how to actually send the post parameters properly for this request. Does sending it in a Map make any difference apart from readability

This is my RestAssured DSL

```
given().
                param("type", "Something").
                param("key1", "value1").
                param("key2", "value2").
                param("key3", "value3").
                header("content-type", "application/json").
                when().
                    post("http://someURL/something").
                then().
                statusCode(200).
                log().everything();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a hash map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Type", "Something");
map.put("Authentication", asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("Key", "key1");
    put("Value", "value1");
}}, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("Key", "key2");
    put("Value", "value2");
}}, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("Key", "key3");
    put("Value", "value3");
}}));
```

And pass it to the body of REST Assured:

```
given().               
        contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        body(map).
when().
        post("http://someURL/something").
then().
        statusCode(200).
        log().everything();
```

You could also create a POJO instead of a map and pass it to the body if you prefer. For this to work you need to have a supported JSON serializer framework in the classpath. For example [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/). See [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String inputPayLaod = "{
    "Type": "Something",
    "Authentication": [
        {
            "Key": "key1",
            "Value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "key2",
            "Value": "value2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "key3",
            "Value": "value3"
        }
    ]
}";

given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
.body(inputPayLoad)
.when()
.post(url)
.then().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Hi Anoop Thanks very much. This worked well but i wanted to try with another approach where I put the key and value into a Map and then send it the same way using contentType like you have show. The only thing I can figure out is how to create the Array structure with Authentication. would you have an idea on that,